# Как присвоить переменной результат скрипта?

Tags: php

Вместо присваивания происходит вывод файла, что не так?

```
$data['content']=include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/modules/viewposts/index.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам помогут [ob-функции](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/modules/viewposts/index.php';
$res = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: .

    -$res = ob_get_contents();
    -ob_end_flush();
    +$res = ob_get_flush();

Comment: Согласен, с clean попутал).

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь присвоить в переменную содержимое файла то используй функцию file_get_contents(), если же ты хочешь присвоить в переменную результат работы скрипта, то просто делай его include(), а внутри подгружаемого скрипта вывод записывай в переменную

Comment: Мне нужно $data['content'] присвоить результат выполнения скрипта находящегося по адресу $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/modules/viewposts/index.php'

Comment: Присвоить переменной результат выполнения скрипта невозможно. Можно присвоить переменной результат выполнения функции. Фактически, вы пытаетесь из спички сделать дерево =)

Comment: Ну так я о чем, нужно данные в /modules/viewposts/index.php собирать в переменную, после инклуда эта переменная будет доступна в материнском скрипте

Answer (score 0):

`include` возвращает пользовательское значение только в случае если в подключаемом файле есть `return`. Смотри пример 5 по [ссылке](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php).